# Change file executable bit across all git branches without conflicts

Tags: git

We've just migrated our repository to git, and setup a bunch of initial branches for our developers. However I've just realised that i should have taken the opportunity to correct the file execute permissions. It doesn't impact release, as the release process corrects this, but makes the repo untidy.

The developers haven't started using the branches yet.

Is there a way to correct the executable bit on all files in all branches without causing subsequent conflicts on merge?

After the execute permissions have been corrected I'm planning on adding a standard config for all developers to set, core.filemode=false, so they don't mess them up again.

Comment: git doesn't keep track of any file permissions except for the executable bit.

Comment: Thanks @JeffPuckettII Sorry I should have been more clear. It's the executable bit I'm trying to fix. At the moment nearly all the files in the repository are set to executable, and most don't need to be. I'll change the question to clarify.

Comment: Since no one has use it yet remake the repo. Keeps silly things out of the history. Also there is no need to setup branches. They are cheap and local in Git. It is better to write down branch conventions in a style guide and have your developers follow the guidelines.

Comment: What do you mean by migrate? Was this a simple `git init`? of so delete the `.git` directory and do `git init .` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First get a list of branches with `git branch`
2. Checkout `master` with `git checkout master`
3. Remove the execute bit from files: `find "$dir" ! -type d -exec chmod -x {} +`
4. Add everything to staging. `git add .`
5. Commit it. `git commit -m "Remove execute perms from all files"`
6. Checkout each other branch in turn and rebase them onto `master`

   ```
   for branch in <LIST_OF_BRANCHES>; do
     git rebase master
   done
   ```

   Where `<LIST_OF_BRANCHES>` are the other branch names separated by a space.

Comment: If the branches have committed changes to the same files that have had the execute bit removed, will this then conflict? Or is git smart enough to just change the executable bit?

Comment: Will "git merge master" work as well? Is rebase preferable in this instance?

Comment: Git is most likely able to manage this. If not you could just `git rebase --abort` but I am pretty sure Git knows how to handle this.

Comment: Why merge? It will if you want that kind of thing in your history.